# How to solve the matrix equation $\sum_iA_i^TA_iXB_iB_i^T=\sum_iA_i^TC_iB_i^T$ efficiently?

Tags: matrix-equations, tensors, matrix-decomposition, tensor-decomposition, multivariate-statistical-analysis

How would I go about solving the matrix equation $\sum_iA_i^TA_iXB_iB_i^T=\sum_iA_i^TC_iB_i^T$ for $X$?

The simplest thing to do would be to, of course, consider $Y=\sum_iA_i^TC_iB_i^T$, vectorise and use Krönecker products.
\begin{align*}
vec(\sum_iA_i^TA_iXB_iB_i^T) &= vec(Y)\\
\implies \sum_ivec(A_i^TA_iXB_iB_i^T) &= vec(Y)\\
\implies \sum_i\big((B_iB_i^T)\otimes(A_i^TA_i)\big)vec(X) &= vec(Y)\\
\implies vec(X) &= \Big(\sum_i\big((B_iB_i^T)\otimes(A_i^TA_i)\big)\Big)^{-1}vec(Y)\\
\end{align*}

I want to solve it without inverting, or if possible even computing any Krönecker products. Is there a computationally efficient way to solve it? The major obstacle seems to be the summation, as if it were not there, I could simply distribute the inverse. Is there a way to write the sum of Krönecker products as the Krönecker product of sums?

Comment: This is sometimes called "multiterm linear matrix equation", [Simoncini slides](https://www.dm.unibo.it/~simoncin/applmath20.pdf)

Comment: TLDR; you can't factor it but there are various ad hoc methods to approximate solution numerically